# Installing and Using Razor Engine in Azure Worker Role

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, actionmailer, azure-worker-roles

Using ActionMailer to render email views.  It leverages the Razor View engine which is nice.  I'd like to push the procesing and rendering of email into an Azure Worker Role.

Has anyone installed and used the Razor view engine in an Azure Worker Role?

Can you provide links or pointers to installing the Razor view engine in an Azure Worker Role?

Thanks!

Comment: Would like to know how this goes for you.  We gave up because a lot of the HTML helpers (@Html.Raw, etc) seem to require some type of HttpContext which really made it a PITA to get anything done.  We moved to just generic string replacement template = string.replace(template, ##Field##, OurValue) since our emails are relatively small.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how it works with ActionMailer, but I am using Razor with [RazorEngine](http://nuget.org/packages/RazorEngine) library. All I had to do is to add System.Web.Razor library to worker project. I also selected "Copy local" option in references. Works great when deployed as cloud service.

Comment: You've been able to deploy RazorEngine to Azure with success? For some reason I cannot. I have Copy Local on the reference set to true but when I deploy to Azure (with my MVC app) and attempt to use it, I get an error saying the assembly or a dependency cannot be found. System.Web.Razor is also included as a reference.